# In Shadowrun 1e, Magic users are said to channel mana through their nervous system. Is this still the case?

Tags: shadowrun

I ask because I think Technomancers do something similiar by becoming biological PANs, and some of their Echoes seem to function through manipulating their nervous system as well.

Comment: Are you asking about an edition comparison, general lore - an affirmation of the 1e rules?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what you mean by "is this **still** the case"? Do you mean has some new Shadowrun 1e book come out that changes that? Are you asking whether that is the case in the newest version of Shadowrun?

Comment: I am asking if this is still canon for mages.

Comment: Lore-wise? Or do you ask what Drain is?

Answer (score 2):

Magic users in Shadowrun are said to channel mana through their body. The concentration to form the magic then causes what is called drain. RAW it means non-bodily damage unless the power is above the user's ability to handle (i.e. if the power of the spell exceeds the magic attribute) and the damage becomes physical if not resisted.
(Leaving out the actual rules at this point - too many pages to write.) The exact mechanism is never really explained or restricted as the ways to do magic differs between the various schools / types of magic users.

Now up to 3e Shadowrun does not know technomancers. These appeared in 4e in the rules and in the book Emergence. 2070s if I remember correctly plus minus a few years.

Technomancers are indeed the "magic users" of the matrix in the regard they can "summon" (technical term compile) spirits (technical term sprites) from the resonance of the matrix as since the second matrix crash the whole system is based on technomancer spirits. Too long to explain here as this story line stretches over multiple source books. The latest Neo Anarchist Streetpedia (about 2080s) has a nice summary in it.

Similar to summoning spirits by magic users the compiling of sprites by technomancers does drain damage.